# What is digital output on sound cards?

Tags: audio

I found my sound driver allows to switch to "digital output". In this mode all sounds just disappear. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: *"In this mode all sounds just disappear"* -- It is an output selector.  The assumption is that you only have one set of speakers, and instead of using the analog speaker output, you are using the digital output connected to an AV receiver (or preamp/processor + power amplifier) and a set of speakers (possibly for more channels than just stereo).

Answer (score 2):

The exact meaning of this may change slightly from card to card but that is referring to either your optical output or (most likely) the (usually) yellow\orange RCA type connector (SPDIF) on the back of the sound card.

You aren't going to hear anything unless that connector is attached to a compatible device. Be careful though because many speakers use red\white **analog** RCA connectors; this type of speaker will not work  with SPDIF (and could theoretically damage your speakers; but that is very unlikely). In general, digital out is meant for connecting to other devices (such as an external amplifier) and not directly to speakers themselves. Speakers which support it are around though, but they are way overpriced because they need extra hardware which is almost entirely pointless (the exception being that if your cable is very long digital signals won't degrade until the signal is beyond saving).

Comment: *"the (usually) yellow RCA type connector"* -- Yellow RCA is usually for composite video.  I've only seen orange (or a generic black or white with a text label) used for digital audio.  *"many speakers use red\white analog RCA connectors"* -- I've only seen RCA connectors on cheap, lo-fi speakers.  *"digital out is meant for connecting to other devices (such as an external amplifier)"* -- not just an amplifier, but a something with a (multichannel) digital-to-analog converter or an all-digital processor.

Comment: The only thing I would disagree with is that many of the best PC speakers do use Red\White RCA. I'm assuming you're a bit of an audiophile so even those may be lame to you but the cost really isn't the issue. I just wanted to point that out so he doesn't try to plug it into them if he has them.

Comment: I was thinking of some pre-packaged stereo systems that have (passive) speakers with RCA connectors.  My comment should be amended to exclude ***active*** speakers (which incorporate a power amplifier or even a DAC for a "digital speaker") that rightfully use a RCA connector for unbalanced line input.  Most "PC speakers" are active speakers.